# Ruby value myseteriously gets lost during exception handling

Tags: ruby

I have condensed my problem to what I believe is a minimum reproducible case:

```
class AbortReading < RuntimeError; end
class SomeError < RuntimeError; end

def rno
  retval = false
  catch(:abort_reading) do
    begin
      yield
    rescue AbortReading 
      puts "throw abort_reading"
      throw :abort_reading
    end # begin
    puts "Setting to true"
    retval = true
  end # catch
ensure # rno
  puts "rno returns #{retval.inspect}"
  retval # return value
end

def rfb
  success = rno do
    begin
      puts "failing"
      fail SomeError
    rescue SomeError
      puts "intercepted SomeError"
      fail AbortReading
    end
  end
  puts "success=#{success.inspect}"
  success
end   

puts rfb
```

I have two methods, `rno` and `rfb`. `rno` is supposed to take a block. It returns true, unless the block raises the exception `AbortReading`, in which case it returns false. Note the somewhat unusual usage of `throw` to jump prematurely to the end of `rno`; this construct is taken from the actual (more complex) code, where it does make sense, and I also used it in my example case, since i feel that the cause of the problem could be in this part.

The method `rfb` uses `rno`, and in its body it first raises a `SomeError` and turns this exception into a `AbortReading`. This somewhat odd construct is also taken from the original implementation.

I would expect that the invocation of `rfb` would result into `false`, since it causes a `AbortReading`, and `rno` would then return then `false` from it. However, `rfb` returns `nil`. This means that the variable `success` inside `rfb` has been allocated, but it never receives the value of `retval`.

Running the code produces the output

```
failing
intercepted SomeError
throw abort_reading
rno returns false
success=nil
```

Note in particular, that `rno` does return false just before it terminates, but inside `rfb`, the value is nil. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the return value from `rno` is actually the result of the `catch` block, which is `nil` because you called `throw :abort_reading` without supplying a return value.

The `ensure` keyword does not implicitly return it just "ensures" this code runs before the method returns as it normally would.

If you want `ensure` to return you would need to do so explicitly using the `return` keyword. e.g.

```
def rno
  retval = false
  catch(:abort_reading) do
    begin
      yield
    rescue AbortReading 
      puts "throw abort_reading"
      throw :abort_reading
    end # begin
    puts "Setting to true"
    retval = true
  end # catch
ensure # rno
  puts "rno returns #{retval.inspect}"
  return retval # return value
end
```

That being said I would not recommend this and rather I would use the fact that you can provide a return value with [`Kernel#throw`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) so we can refactor your code to

```
def rno
  retval = catch(:abort_reading) do
    begin
      yield
      puts "Setting to true"
      true
    rescue AbortReading 
      puts "throw abort_reading"
      throw :abort_reading, false
    end # begin
  end # catch
ensure # rno
  puts "rno returns #{retval.inspect}"
end
```

Here, in the event of an `AbortReading` error, we are throwing the symbol `:abort_reading` along with the return value `false` so the result of the `catch` block will be `false` when it catches `:abort_reading` or `true` if the `yield` does not result in an `AbortReading` error.

Now the output of calling `puts rfb` is

```
failing
intercepted SomeError
throw abort_reading
rno returns false
success=false
false
```